# for loop > if-statement ($foo=$array[$i])

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to simplify some code where I have an extremely long switch statement (20+ cases). The only thing I need from the switch is to increment a counter.

The currently working switch is set up like this:

```
//multidimensional-array is above
while ($responses = mysql_fetch_assoc($surveydata)){
    switch($responses['cou_mun']){
        case "New York":
            $targetCities[0][1]++;
            break;
        case …
    }
}
```

I have the following multi-dimensional array and for loop:

```
//           [index]   'city name',count,minimum
$targetCities[0]=array('New York City',0,250);
$targetCities[1]=array('Los Angeles',0,250);
// 20 more

$responses = mysql_fetch_assoc($surveydata); //this is taken from the while-loop when I comment out the while() and switch().

for ($i=0; $i < count($targetCities); $i++){

    if ($responses['cou_mun'] == $targetCities[$i][0]){$targetCities[$i][1]++;}
    else{$nontargetcity++;}

    echo "<li><span>" . $targetCities[$i][0] . "</span><span>" . $targetCities[$i][1] . "</span>" . amountUnderMin($targetCities[$i][1],$targetCities[$i][2]) . "<span>" . $targetCities[$i][2] . "</span><span>" . cityMinMet($targetCities[$i][1],$targetCities[$i][2]) . "</span></li>";
}
```

`$responses['cou_mun']` returns a city-name (such as "Los Angeles").

*The only thing that's not working is the `if` (increments the counter).*

I expect the 2nd dimension of the current $targetCities to be incremented, however when the line is printed/echo'd, it still shows as `0` (yet I can see in the Db that there is more than one "Los Angeles").

P.S. I made sure the names in the array exactly match (spell+whitespace+case) the name options in the Db.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: the `$nontargetcity` counter is returning 21 (the number of cases).

Comment: Did you try doing an echo immediately after the increment to see what the value looks like -- and to verify the line gets executed?

Comment: Have you tried echoing out of the `if` block to see if it's actually reached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$surveydata = mysql_query( … );
$targetCities[0]=array('New York',0,250);
$targetCities[1]=array('Los Angeles',0,250);
//etc
//etc
//etc
$respondentCities=array();

while ($responses = mysql_fetch_assoc($surveydata)) {
    array_push($respondentCities,$responses['cou_mun']);
} //i'm sorting the values in $respondentCities because i need them later

//function amountUnderMin(){…}
//function cityMinMet(){…}

for ($i=0; $i < count($targetCities); $i++){
    foreach($respondentCities as $respondentCity){
        if($respondentCity==$targetCities[$i][0]){$targetCities[$i][1]++;break;}
    }
    echo "<li><span>" . $targetCities[$i][0] . "</span><span>" . $targetCities[$i][1] . "</span>" . amountUnderMin($targetCities[$i][1],$targetCities[$i][2]) . "<span>" . $targetCities[$i][2] . "</span><span>" . cityMinMet($targetCities[$i][1],$targetCities[$i][2]) . "</span></li>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Array literals allow nesting:

```
$targetCities = array(
    array('New York City',0,250),
    array('Los Angeles',0,250),
);
```

Use associative arrays:

```
$targetCities = array(
    array('name' => 'New York City', 'count' => 0, 'minimum' => 250),
    array('name' => 'Los Angeles', 'count' => 0, 'minimum' => 250),
);
```

Use `foreach` instead of `for(;;)`:

```
foreach($targetCities as $key => $city) {
    if ($responses['cou_mun'] == $city['name']) {
        $targetCities[$key]['count']++;
    }
```

Use var_dump() to debug the value of a variable:

```
var_dump($responses['cou_num']);

foreach($targetCities as $key => $city) {
    var_dump($city['name'], $responses['cou_mun'] == $city['name']);
```

Comment: His logic is sound; this is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: I also think the `$targetCities` array is coming from a `mysql_fetch_array()`

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array()` returns associative arrays

Comment: @arnaud576875: oh cool! thanks (trying it now). I was trying to do the associative array at first, but I was getting the syntax wrong when I was calling it. <i>should there be a comma on the last sub-array?</i>

Comment: $responses is an associative array from mysql that I need to compare $targetCities to.

Comment: yes you can leave the trailing comma, it's allowed (and convenient)

Comment: a selection of values from the Db's cou_mun column are: `"Franklin County", "Anne Arundel County", "DeKalb County", "Butler County", "DeKalb County", "Autauga County", "Hawaii County"`, so number recruited for Hawaii County should be at least 1 :x

Comment: @arnaud576875: with the `switch`, it was encased in a `while` loop, so I added it, and now it's advancing. **however**, $city['name'] is not advancing (it says on the first city name)